# Program type already present: androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry while generating signed APK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have an Android project which has to include a Unity project as well. Without importing the Unity project, I can successfully generated the release build APK (signed APK). But after including Unity project, I am facing this issue:

[image]

4 subsequent errors are:

```
Program type already present: androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry
Error: Program type already present: androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry
```

Steps I've taken to include the unity project into Android project:

1. Export the Unity project
2. Build the exported project as a library
3. Include the .aar file in the native android project

By native android app level gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
//                arguments  '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
                cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-frtti", "-fexceptions"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'/*, 'arm64-v8a'*/
        }

    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }

//        ndkBuild {
//            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
//        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }



    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }



    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}



configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module: 'annotation'
    // added after getting com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnimRes
}



repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://google.bintray.com/tensorflow'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'tensorflow-lite', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"

    implementation project(':openCVLibrary341')
//    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation project(':macelibrary')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation(project(':unity')){

        exclude group: 'androidx.arch.core' // added after reading the below linked question

    }
}
```

Unity Project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb']
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    /*buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }*/

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

**This question is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587580/program-type-already-present-androidx-arch-core-internal-safeiterablemapentry)**, but there is no answer to the original question and I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask about the issue. The only difference is, after reading this question, I removed Firebase from Unity project and tried to generate signed APK, that didn't help either, same error.

Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

I managed to solve this issue by removing the androidx.* libraries from the **libs** directory of the exported unity project.

---

### Reason:

androidx.* libraries were already being included in the native android project. While including the Unity project as library, the library also had all these androidx.* libraries and these were causing this issue.

As it turned out, while exporting a Unity project as native Android project, Unity by default includes these androidx.* libraries. They are only needed if we want to build an APK out of that project. But for building a library out of it, these androidx.* libraries are not required.